# Should OAuth 2.0 "state" parameter be unique for each request or can it be stored?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am not sure if I have to randomly generate a unique "state" parameter on each request, or if I can use the same string everytime and save it as a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to use a "random" value.

There is no requirement that it be "truly" unique.

However, it should be used by the Client to track the session. If the same State parameter was sent with each request, then there is a vulnerability of some intercepter forging a response similar to cross site scripting attacks.

Best practice would be to use a "random" value for each request that in theory does not repeat.

-jim

Comment: I agree with you. Furthermore to this answer, I would like to share with you [this specification draft](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bradley-oauth-jwt-encoded-state) that tries to propose a mechanism whereby multiple state attributes can be encoded into a JWT. In this case the state parameter in not a random value (but may be unique).